# Can I mention the same experience in 2 sections on my cv?

Tags: teaching, cv, summer-school

I am an incoming physics PhD student. A few weeks ago I participated in organizing a summer school at my current university and delivered a small lecture. I would like to include this experience on my cv (in the 'teaching experiences' section), but I was wondering if it's appropriate to also include my lecture on the 'talks and presentation' part. Can I mention the same experience in 2 sections on my cv? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not doing that for an application focused CV as it can seem like "padding". But you can make it work if you are careful to avoid that suggestion.

An alternative option is to list it both places but to annotate the second reference with a pointer to the first, making it clear.

Just don't make it seem that you are listing two things when it is really a repetition. And, if the two "sections" are sparse, you can also combine them. "teaching" and "talks and presentations" are conceptually pretty similar.